# Como agrupar os registros por dia usando Unix Timestamp?

Tags: mysql

Eu gostaria de agrupar os resultados pelos dias que pertencem ao período definido na query.

```
SELECT count(*) FROM historico WHERE contato_id IN (19, 45) AND createdAt BETWEEN 1556668800 AND 155936879;
```

Qual seria a melhor solução para este caso?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Partindo do princípio que o campo `createdAt` representa um tempo em unix. 
Se você criar uma coluna formatada com o dia, talvez você possa usá-la para agrupar os registros.

```sql
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(createdAt), '%d/%m/%Y') AS dia,
       COUNT(*) AS total
FROM   historico 
WHERE  contato_id IN ( 19, 45 ) 
       AND createdAt >= 1556668800 
       AND createdAt <= 155936879 
GROUP  BY dia
```

**Edit 1**
Se seu campo não representa um tempo em unix, você pode tentar dessa forma:

```sql
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(createdAt, '%d/%m/%Y') AS dia,
       COUNT(*) AS total
FROM   historico 
WHERE  contato_id IN ( 19, 45 ) 
GROUP  BY dia
```

Veja este [fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7029b1/1) que ilustra a query acima funcionando. Repare que há 2 inserts com a mesma data e um que não cai no range `IN (19, 45)`

Comment: @VictorCarnaval Editei a resposta com uma nova possibilidade e exemplo online.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, solucionou o meu problema.